# E is closed if every limit point of E is a point of E?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

E is closed if every limit point of E is a point of E?

Should that be "E is closed if every point of E, is a limit point"?

I don't understand. Limit points are essentially points that hug other points. How can a limit point of E, not be a point of E?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure of $E$, in a topological space $X$ containing it, is $E$ together its limit point. This proves your statement: "E is closed if every limit point of E is a point of E" which is true.

Conversely, a closed subset of a topological space can have no limit points: for example $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, but it hasn't limit points; it has only isolated point and it is called *discrete*.

Closed subspaces such that "every point of E is a limit point" are called *perfect*.

Finally, $E=\{\frac 1n:n\in\mathbb N-\{0\}\}$ has $0$ as limit point and $0\notin E$; note that $E$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Many edits :P. Thanks for (growing) bonus information

Comment: Bonus informations and edits helps to a better understanding.

Comment: Certainly(my thank you was definitely not sarcasm). I hadn't read discrete or perfect so thank you

Comment: $0\not\in E$ and "A point $p$ is a limit point of $E$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$". So is this point $p$ not necessarily $p\in E$?

Comment: Exactly, is not require to $p$ to belongs at $E$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is correct as is: "$E$ is closed if every limit point of $E$ is a point of $E$."

To see how a limit point could not be a point of $E$, consider the (open) interval $E=(0,1)$. Then for any $\epsilon$ neighborhood of zero, there is some positive number ($\min\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for instance) which is contained in the neighborhood and $E$, but $0$ itself is not in $E$. Hence $E$ is not closed.

Comment: That's not the definition of a limit point; if $X = \{x\}$, then $X$ has _no_ limit points.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, I had apparently been using the wrong definition all this time.

Comment: But $\{0\}\not\in E$, so $\{0\}$ is not a point of $E$ right?

Comment: And if $\{0\}$ is not a point of $E$ it isn't possibly a limit point?

Comment: What limit point is not a point of E?

Comment: @mehtrekspayz $0$ in this case is in fact a limit point even though it isn't contained in the interval.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt But doesn't a limit point have to be a point in $E$ by definition? - Or is this sort of like the lim sup, lim inf thing again?

Comment: @mehtrekspayz It shouldn't be. What is your definition of a limit point?

Comment: @Peter "A point $p$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if every neighbourhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$" I suppose it doesn't specify

Comment: @mehtrekspayz Right, so consider the point $0$ in this example where $E=(0,1)$. Any neighborhood of $0$ has some (nonzero) point in the interval $(0,1)$ despite the fact that $0$ itself is not in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is closed but no need every point is a [limit point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point), say $E=\{0\}$, it has no limit point but it's closed in $\mathbb{R}$